# Try to get jQuery working on a Wordpress site (Bones theme)

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I try to get jQuery working on a Wordpress site. It's all working on my no-wordpress version but i have hard time to adapt it in worpress. I tried to run a simple script:

I have this in my theme functions.php:

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

function add_my_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'test', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/test.js', array('jquery')
    );
}

add_action('init', 'add_my_script');
```

And this is the test script i want to run, test.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   alert('hi');
});
```

I don't know what i am doing wrong :S

Comment: WordPress has jQuery by default, no need to include your own copy.  Also, with Bones, you can go to `library/bones.php` and just copy/paste the register and enqueue lines in there, just remember to change the name and file path.  Start looking at line 119 for the enqueuing stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure the code in your functions.php is actually enqueuing the
   scripts you need (view source of the page).
2. As far as I remember, WordPress enqueues jquery by default.
3. If you want to use the jquery version that wordpress enqueued, then
   you have to use the jQuery keyword instead of $ eg:

   jQuery(document).ready(function() {
          alert('hi');
          jQuery('div').hide();
       });
4. if you want to use another version of jQuery (i prefer this way)
   then you have to DEREGISTER the enqueued-by-wordpress version of
   jquery. Then you have to register the version of jquery and then
   enqueue it. This applies for all scripts included by WordPress.
   Remember: deregister, register, enqueue.
5. The enqueue functions should be inside your add_my_script function
6. add_my_script function should hook to the wp_enqueue_scripts action: add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','add_my_script');
7. [Codex is your friend](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script).